# A function is not continous in$(C[a,b],\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove the identity function $I:((C[a,b],\mathbb{R}), d_{\infty}) \rightarrow ((C[a,b],\mathbb{R}),d_{1})$ is not continous.
Where $C[a,b]=\{f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$| f is continous in $[a,b] \}$, $d_{\infty}(f,g)=$sup{$|f(x)-g(x)| \big{|} x\in [a,b]$} ,
$d_{1}(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b}|f(x)-g(x)|dx$.

I tried to create a subsequence of functions but I want to know if there is another easy form to resolve

Answer (score 3):

$I$ is continuous

Let $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Then $\int_a^b|f_n-f| \leq d_{\infty}(f_n,f)(b-a) \to 0$

> $I:((C[a,b],\mathbb{R}), d_{1}) \rightarrow ((C[a,b],\mathbb{R}),d_{\infty})$ is not continous.

Indeed take $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$

Comment: I agree, this question seems suspect.

Comment: @Math1000. Maybe the proposer got the domain and range of $I$ reversed